# What is the next word in this sequence?

Tags: word, pattern, letters

What word follows AMPLE in this sequence:

> REDDEN
>
> SEAM
>
> PLEA
>
> REARED
>
> DENSE
>
> AMPLE
>
> ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Going by the three words

> SEAM
>
> PLEA
>
> REARED
>
> Since these words are formed by continuation Ample is formed by SE "AM-PLE" leaving A and the next word that can be formed with the remaining letters of the next word

Would it be

> AREA

This would be followed by REDDEN followed by SEAM making it a full sequence or just saying

> The first 17 letters are repeated

Comment: You are right, but there is a more perfect sounding explanation.

Comment: does that make the cut?

Comment: I will accept this.  An easy way to explain is to just say the first 17 letters get repeated.

Comment: ok I shall edit